# To find limit of a sequence: $a_n=n\left(\sqrt[n]{ea}- \sqrt[n]{a}\right),\,a>0.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, cauchy-sequences

I have to find limit of the following [sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IamdG.jpg):

Suppose $a>0$, consider the sequence $a_n=n\left(\sqrt[n]{ea}- \sqrt[n]{a}\right),\,n\ge1 \,\text{then} \lim_{n \to \infty}a_n\,\text{is}\ldots$

I tried to solve this problem and considered $a$ to be a very small positive number and I got the result that sequence converges to $0$.

But actually the answer is that sequence converges to 1.

How shall I proceed to find limit of this sequence.

Comment: Have you already covered functions, their limits, derivatives ,etc.?

Comment: "I got the result that sequence converges to 0" You could explain precisely what you did to get this.

Answer (score 3):

One may write, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
a_n&=n\left(e^{\frac{\large\ln(ea)}n}-e^{\large\frac{\ln(a)}n} \right)
\\&=n\left(e^{\large\frac{1+\ln(a)}n}-e^{\large\frac{\ln(a)}n} \right)
\\&=n \cdot e^{\large\frac{\ln(a)}n}\left(e^{\large\frac{1}n}-1 \right)
\\&= e^{\large\frac{\ln(a)}n}\cdot\frac{e^{\frac{1}n}-1}{\frac{1}n}
\end{align}
$$ then one may conclude with
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{e^{\frac{1}n}-1}{\frac{1}n}=1.
$$

Comment: @AbhishekChandra You are welcome. I have a lot of practice ;)

Answer (score 0):

$$n\left(\sqrt[n]{ea}-\sqrt[n]a\right)=n\sqrt[n]a\left(\sqrt[n]e-1\right)=\sqrt[n]a\,\frac{\sqrt[n]e-1}{\frac1n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\cdot\left[\left(e^x\right)'\right]_{x=0}=1\cdot e^0=1$$

Answer (score 0):

The function $$A:[1,+\infty)\to\Bbb R: x\mapsto xa^{\frac{1}{x}}(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1)$$ is continuous as a product of composite functions of continuous functions.

Hence, if the limit when $x\to+\infty$ exists, it is the same along any sequence $(x_{n})_{n}$ such that $x_{n}\to+\infty$ as $n\to+\infty$. We shall prove that the limit exists and thus for the sequence $x_{n}=n$ as well.

We have:

\begin{align*}
&\lim_{x\to+\infty}A(x)\\
&=\lim_{x\to+\infty}xa^{\frac{1}{x}}(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1)\\
&=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{a^{\frac{1}{x}}(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1)}{1/x}
\end{align*}

Here, we have a $\frac{0}{0}$ limit and we can thus use L'Hospital's rule. It yields:

\begin{align*}
&\lim_{x\to+\infty}A(x)\\
&=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{a^{\frac{1}{x}}(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1)}{1/x}\\
&=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\ln(a)a^{\frac{1}{x}}\left(-\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1)+a^{\frac{1}{x}}\left(-\frac{1}{x^{2}}\right)e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{-\frac{1}{x^{2}}}\\
&=\lim_{x\to+\infty}\ln(a)a^{\frac{1}{x}}(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1)+e^{\frac{1}{x}}a^{\frac{1}{x}}\\
&= 1
\end{align*}